# Substitute AngularJS or BreezeJS ajax objects with my own to allow for a server-side proxy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I have some idea of what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to go about it best using Angular and Breeze, combined through the HotTowel template.  Our internal web app talks to an internal web service on another host, so we run into some cross-domain problems (CORS).  To resolve this, I've (in a previous project) used a simple server-side proxy to bounce the requests.  To do this, though, I need to attach the proxy URL to any outbound data requests.  So if breeze is ultimately looking for `http://example-service-host.example/odata/Entity` I want to change that to `http://example-site.example/proxy.ashx?url=<encodedURL>`

But I'm not sure how to go about this. HotTowel replaces the Breeze ajax service with Angular's `$http`.  So I should be able to inject an $http wrapper into there or modify where Angular gets $http from to put the wrapper in even deeper.

The documentation for both is just leading me to suspect that any loose wrapper will encounter issues as it won't be a perfect fake for the real thing.  Any guidance on doing this or suggestions on where I can inject a wrapper?  Alternatively, am I doing the server-side proxy the hard way and there's a better way to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the ajax calls within Breeze (which uses jQuery as the default).  Here is a link to the documentation about how to do it:
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax